# How to convert an array of publishers to one publisher of an array

Tags: swift, combine

Let's say we have:

```
Array<AnyPublisher<T,Never>>
```

And we want to convert it into

```
AnyPublisher<Array<t>,Never>>
```

What approach would you take to solve this?

Comment: When does the new publisher emit? Does it publish when any one of the input publishers emits? Or does it only emit when each one of the input publishers has emitted a new value?

Comment: In other words, do you want to combine the input publishers using `combineLatest`, or do you want to combine them using `zip`?

Comment: Here's a blog that does something similar to `combineLatest` functionality: https://danieltull.co.uk/blog/2019/08/04/combine-latest-collection/. But, in a nutshell, this isn't a trivial thing and requires implementing a new publisher

Comment: @robmayoff I am not experienced with Combine, but your question pointed out the problem with my question.
What I had in my mind was that the new Publisher will wait for all the Publishers in the array to return a value, put them all in an array and emit that array.
Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @NewDev oh thank you for the article. I'm reading it right now, it is well written.